# SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL) ----backup---> error ! must delete a backup before creating a new one

Tags: heroku

Hi what can I do about this I can't capture a backup from heroku

I am using shared database

It always shows...

SHARED_DATABASE (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  error

!    must delete a backup before creating a new one

How can I delete recent backups?

Thank you.

Comment: I finally know the answer.....


**heroku pgbackups:capture --expire**

Comment: Or you can also do heroku pgbackups:destroy BACKUP_ID > for those who encounter also my problem. thanks to myself hahaha JOKE

Answer (score 77):

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --expire
```

this will create the backup :)

> --expire automatically deletes the oldest existing manual backup

Comment: --expire automatically deletes the oldest existing manual backup

Answer (score 8):

You can list backups

```
heroku pgbackups
```

Then delete one by typing it's ID

```
heroku pgbackups:destroy b003
```

More information can be found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups).